Non-Constant Morphisms Between Projective Curves: Examples Beyond Maps to Projective Space
I'm studying morphisms between projective curves and have encountered numerous examples where one of the curves is a projective space ($\mathbb{P}^n$). While these are helpful, I'm interested in broadening my understanding. Could someone provide a concrete example of a non-constant morphism between two projective curves, where neither curve is isomorphic to a projective space? Like morphism between Artin-Schrier curves.

Here are a couple of examples:

For any elliptic curve $E$ multiplication by $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a self-map $n \colon E \to E$ of degree $n^2$.

For any curve $X$ of positive genus $g$, if $L$ is a line bundle such that $L^n \cong \mathcal{O}$ (and $n > 0$ is minimal with this property) then
$$
Y = \mathrm{Spec}_X(\mathcal{O}_X \oplus L \oplus \dots \oplus L^{n-1})
$$
is a curve of genus $n(g - 1) + 1$ endowed with an etale map $Y \to X$ of degree $n$.



Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand your elliptic curve example but I am not familiar with etale maps. I'm currently working through Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves and learning about the correspondence between morphisms of curves and extensions of their function fields. I understand the concept well for maps from a curve to projective space. However, I'm curious about examples where both curves are not projective spaces. I am finding it difficult to define map when both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are distinct curves.
